# Angular 2 will only compile with the wrong path

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code

When importing a class into a component in my Angular 2 app, the compiler complains that the path is wrong and that it can't find the file. I can change it to the wrong path and it will compile but won't run, because the path is wrong. I have the app watching for file updates, so I have been compiling it with the wrong path and then going back in and changing it to the right path and then it works. Any ideas why this might be happening?

Won't compile, but will run if previously compiled with the wrong path:

`import { Item } from '../../../../../+models/index';`

Will compile, but won't run since it is the wrong path

`import { Item } from '../../../../+models/index';`

Comment: Are you using angular-cli?

Comment: I don't believe so, I actually got this project from someone else and cut it down to the bare bones before building

Comment: How do you start project?

Comment: npm start, which runs "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" \"sass --watch app/styles:compiled_sass \" \"postcss -w --use autoprefixer compiled_sass/*.css -d stylesheets/ \" \"postcss -w --use autoprefixer compiled_sass/*/*.css -d stylesheets/ \" ",

Comment: I think you should start from creating normal build system on webpack or angular-cli. I see only one reason of this behavior: root directory for compiler and server is different. Build system should solve this problem. If you want I will help you.